# Swift: How do I print out the value of a dictionary key inside a string expression?

Tags: dictionary, swift

For some reason, I just can't make this expression work:

```
let expandedBio: Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = ["name":"Saurabh", "profession":"developer", "language":"java", "employed": true]

if let employed : AnyObject = expandedBio["employed"] {
    println("\(expandedBio[\"name\"]) is not available")
}
```

How do I output the `println` statement? I get the error

```
Unexpected "" character  error in string interpolation
```

How do I do this right?

Comment: This problem is solved in swift 2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In current version of Swift you have to put value in its own constant/variable first, then use that.

```
if let employed : AnyObject = expandedBio["employed"] {
    let t = expandedBio["name"]
    println("\(t) is not available")
}
```

Comment: I had to use `let t : AnyObject? = expandedBio["name"]`

Comment: not necessarily but recommended for a better readability.

Comment: While the "if let employed" already expects that "employed" might be nil (and so can handle that situation), the simple assignment of "t" might result in a nil value -> "Because it is possible to request a key for which no value exists, a dictionary's subscript returns an optional value of the dictionary's value type." -> Thus you should make that optional clear by defining t as "AnyObject?"

Comment: This problem is solved in swift 2.1